# Are Hollowtech II bottom bracket normal?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I've just installed a brand new Ultegra 6600 crank/bb on my brand new frame. Everything is fine and properly installed, but the crank doesn't rotate as freely as a square taper BB. The bike is not yet ready to be ridden waiting for some parts.

Will the bb break down?

Comment: Was the BB shell of the frame faced before fitting?

Comment: Did you use a dynamometric wrench (in case this is not a press-fit bb)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the BB installed properly (no cross threading) it is normal to have a little bit of resistance when they are new.  But honestly they don't feel as "free" as a square taper BB because of the resistance from the bearing seals.

Also, be sure to check the drive side cup of the BB every 3-6 months.  If you ride in wet conditions aim more for the 3 month side.  That cup has a tendency to seize up.  It happens with all steel ball outboard/hollowtech BB's and the only answer is a ceramic bearing model or a Chris King BB.

Comment: If the bearings seize up, pop out the seal with an old blunt blade (without damaging it) and flush out with wd-40, dry and regrease thoroughly.